# numeric input does not adapt to scene unit setup?

Tags: units

choosing cm in scene > units > length does not have any effect when beveling an edge: pressing 1 results in 100 cm just like pressing 1 with meters results in 1m. the correct behavior should be to take the input at face value. 1 should be 1. When working with small objects and you need a 0.5cm bevel you currently need to put in .005

...or am I doing it wrong?

setting different unit Scale like 0.01 or 100 does not change the numeric interpretation either btw

blender-2.80-155c62b070a9-win64

Comment: Is it something that happens in all the numeric input operations (e.g. extruding...)or just for the bevel operator?

Comment: it seems to be a bevel issue. inset and extrude work as expected. with cm as units entering 22 extrudes by 22cm. so, bug?

Comment: It's an incosistency in the input management. It's not working as espected and it's a part of a new feature. I would mark it as a bug, but it's just my opinion.

Comment: The problem has been fixed in the current builds

Comment: Great. I'll vote to close this as a bug fixes.